# How to check if siblings row exists or not jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple rows of Class and student, these are being generated dynamically, there may or may not be rows with class student which are sibling to a class, i want to count number of rows with class student after a particular Class using a jquery in side a foreach loop.

```js
jQuery('.class').each(function(e) {
      // count number of student after each class row
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row clearfix class">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Class</h5>
    <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
      <option value="2">High School</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 1</h5>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 2</h5>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="row clearfix class">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Class</h5>
      <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="2">High School</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 1</h5>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 2</h5>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 3</h5>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix class">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Class</h5>
      <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="2">High School</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why has the first class 2 students as siblings and the second class 3 students as childs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) to get all the `.student` elements until the next `.class`. For the last class, it will return all the remaining students.

Your HTML has an error, one of the `.class` DIVs was missing `</div>`, so the students were nested inside rather than after it.

```js
jQuery('.class').each(function(e) {
  var students = $(this).nextUntil(".class", ".student").length;
  var classname = $(this).find("h5").text();
  console.log(`Class: ${classname}, students = ${students}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row clearfix class">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Class 1</h5>
    <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
      <option value="2">High School</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 1</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 2</h5>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row clearfix class">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Class 2</h5>
      <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="2">High School</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 1</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 2</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix student">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5 class="card-inside-title">Student 3</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix class">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h5 class="card-inside-title">Class 3</h5>
      <select name="input" class="form-control show-tick check_valid" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
        <option value="2">High School</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, @Barmar, you beat me to it by 7 seconds, and I haven't even started with the explanations, which would have been exactly the same as yours! :D

Comment: @cars10m It's not the same ;) Barmer also fixed the markup (hence the `filter` selector in the `.nextUntil()` call otherwise the last "class" would also have "students")

Comment: That is true - I "fixed" it in my solution in a different way by adding the closing `</div>` in the markup, assuming it was unintentionally left out.

Comment: That's what I did as well, because I was getting incorrect results first.

Comment: Well, something to have a good laugh about anyway! I will remove my redundant answer then ;-)